# Send message on iPhone 4S using PC Bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, iphone

I have successfully paired a Bluetooth keyboard with my iPhone 4S, and it works great for composing messages.

However, I can't find a way to <kbd>send</kbd> a message from the Messages app using just the keyboard.
I've tried <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

There's [a thread on Apple's site that covers the same topic](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2715473?start=0&tstart=0) - one of the posts alluded to a "send" button on a full-featured iPhone keyboard.

Does anyone know what extended key code or combination the "official" keyboard is sending?  If not, is there a way to find out?

Comment: Someone else was asking for similar support in a third-party app: http://www.shapeservices.com/en/support/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1053

Answer (score 2):

In Mail for the Mac you can send the current message using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, so maybe try that?

On my PC keyboard, the <kbd>Win</kbd> key sends a <kbd>Cmd</kbd> in Mac OS X, yours is probably the same.

Comment: Good point, I hadn't tried the <Win> key yet.
Sadly, that didn't work.  I tried <Shift>+<Win>+<D>, then a whole bunch of combinations of <modifier>+<Win>+<Enter>, but I still can't get it to send the current message.

Comment: @mskfisher Then I'm sorry, out of ideas. Hope you find a way, that would be really useful!